# SQL query - How to display points in the last 24 hours?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a website with points system, similar to Stackoverflow;

This is the code I'm using to display top users (for all time):

```
SELECT id, username, active, points 
FROM users 
WHERE active='1' 
ORDER BY points DESC
```

But how can I show the top users in 24 hours (also points)?

Comment: You need to create `datetime` field too.

Comment: You cannot create a points system based website without the Stack Overflow's consent.

Comment: @Charlie, I don't think SO has patent over ALL point-driven websites ;)  As long as silvius' site isn't a complete copy, it shouldn't be any legal problem.

Comment: @Kris C, it is. I hoped to have more support on that, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to make a special table that would record when (and how many) points the user received.

**EDIT**

E.g. table `points`

```
user_id   time         awarded_points
-------------------------------------
1         1298745681   10
...
```

Then you just ask for the points awarded today with `WHERE time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())` or in the last 24 hours `WHERE time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-24*3600`.

Example use:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.active, SUM(p.awarded_points) AS points
FROM points AS p
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
AND u.active = '1'
GROUP BY p.user_id
ORDER BY points DESC
```

I'd also suggest adding a LIMIT to the query, especially if your site grows big.

Comment: but how should the table look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your need another table, where all users activites/points would be write
And than join with this table, and condition to 24h

Answer (score 0):

Add a table recording the points each user receives and when with a foreign key relation to the users table

For example a table named points with the following columns

- userid (FK to users table)
- datetimeallocated
- numberofpoints
- other columns of interest e.g. user who allocated the points etc

You then need to query this table e.g.

```
SELECT SUM(numberofpoints), userid
FROM points
WHERE datetimeallocated >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY SUM(numberofpoints) DESC
```